# Set selected value of combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I want to set selected value of a combobox

I am receiving a DataTable from the database looking like this:

[image]

this Datatable is bound to this combobox.

```
<ComboBox
    DisplayMemberPath="KommuneNavn"
    SelectedValuePath="KommuneNr"
    ItemsSource="{Binding KommuneNavne}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding KommuneNr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"        
    Margin="3"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsUdenlandskAdresse, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNotConverter}}" />
```

In my viewmodel I have a specific `KommuneNr` stored in a property. I would like to have my combobox set to show the `KommuneNavn` that matches with this `KommuneNr`.

Example:

I have the `KommuneNr` 101 stored in my viewmodel, the `KommuneNavn` that matches with this is `København` I would then like to have my combobox be set to `København`.

This was pretty difficult to explain, I hope I am making sense. Otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: I can find nothing wrong with the code you have shared. Might be something wrong with your ViewModel (or DataContext).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KommuneNavne` must be an `ObservableCollection`, and in your `ViewModel` you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (not described in this example)

```
<ComboBox 
      ItemsSource="{Binding KommuneNavne}"
      SelectedValue="{Binding KommuneNr, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
      DisplayMemberPath="KommuneNavn"
      SelectedValuePath="KommuneNr"
/>
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<KommuneNavn> KommuneNavne
    {
        get { value = _kommuneNavne; } //=> _kommuneNavne;
        set
        {
            _kommuneNavne = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(KommuneNavne));
        }
    }

    public long KommuneNr
    {
        get { value = _kommuneNr; } //=> _kommuneNr;
        set
        {
            if (_kommuneNr == value) return;
            _kommuneNr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(KommuneNr));
        }
    }


    private void SetValue(int valueToSet)
    {
        KommuneNr = valueToSet;
    }

}
```

Comment: *"KommuneNavne must be an ObservableCollection"* No, it has to be an `IEnumerable`, doesn't have to be more than that.

Comment: So I can't use a DataTable for this?

Comment: @BorisGrunwald Not directly, no - you should at least use a ViewModel for the entries (a simple class with two properties would work) e.g.: `public class Kommune { public string KommuneNavn { get; set; } public int KommuneNr { get; set; } }` and put them in a `List<Kommune>` or something similar. If this list can change during rutime, I'd go with Celso's suggestion of using an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I can work out a solution from this answer.